# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BAGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need your help, I want to enter a value into field "foto" but I get some error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BAGIN_ARRAY.
this my DAO

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public String detinst (String json)throws Exception{
            sesi = sf.openSession();
            tx = sesi.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("--------DAO---------");
            System.out.println("22222222222");
            installasimodel hasil = gson.fromJson(json, installasimodel.class);
            int tid = hasil.getTid();
            System.out.println("TID :"+tid);
            SQLQuery query=sesi.createSQLQuery("select * from istlsi_edc_tkn_tebel where tid='"+tid+"'");
            List<installasimodel> result = query.addEntity(installasimodel.class).list();
            String inst = gson.toJson(result);
            System.out.println("hasil query :"+inst);
////////////////////////////
String intoFoto ="asanskasndjksnds";

/////////////////////////////

            sesi.close();
            return inst;
        }
```

this my model

```
........    
@Column(name="id_spv")
        private int id_spv;

        @Column(name="own_mrchn")
        private String own_mrchn;

        @Column(name="phone")
        private String phone;

        @Column(name="kde_pos")
        private int kde_pos;

        @Column(name="sts_edc")
        private int sts_edc;

        @Column(name="ms")
        private String ms;

        @Column(name="sc")
        private String sc;

        @Column(name="foto")
        private String foto;

        @Column(name="ttd")
        private String ttd;
..............
```

this a json if the program start

```
 [{..........."phone":"8555555","kde_pos":121212,"sts_edc":0,"foto":""}]
```

if we look at json above, the field "foto" is empty, what must I do to be like this

```
[{..........."phone":"8555555","kde_pos":121212,"sts_edc":0,"foto":"asanskasndjksnds"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the enclosing "[]" from your json, because Gson expects a single JSON object, not an array of JSON objects.
You serialize a List of models into JSON:

```
List<installasimodel> result = query.addEntity(installasimodel.class).list();
String inst = gson.toJson(result); //this serializes a list and the resulting JSON is a JSON array of objects ([{...}]).
```

But in your deserialization code you are trying to deserialize the array into a single model:

```
installasimodel hasil = gson.fromJson(json, installasimodel.class);
```

So your either you need to change your serialization to serialize the first object of the list (assuming the length is always 1): `gson.toJson(result.get(0))`
or you need to change change deserialization so that GSON expects a list:

```
List<installasimodel> result = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<installasimodel>>(){}.getType() );
```

Comment: sory did you mean like this

SQLQuery query=sesi.createSQLQuery("select * from istlsi_edc_tkn_tebel where tid='"+tid+"'");
  List<installasimodel> result = gson.fromJson(query, new TypeToken<List<installasimodel>>(){}.getType() );
  String inst = gson.toJson(result);
I get
The method fromJson(String, Type) in the type Gson is not applicable for the arguments (SQLQuery, Type)

Comment: I udpated my answer. I think query.addEntity(installasimodel.class).list(); should always return a single result. If that's right you just need to change single line from your original solution: "String inst = gson.toJson(result);" to "String inst = gson.toJson(result.get(0));"